# conditional execution of steps after called function in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Requirement: Based upon IF condition in the called function: myfunc, ***echo hello*** in the for loop should not get executed and control should go to the next iteration.

In the below script, when the value of k becomes 2 and 3, echo hello should not get executed.

This is the script that I am trying to develop but no success.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

    myfunc() {
      if [[ $k -gt 1 ]]; then
        echo "in the loop"
        return
       else
         echo continue
      fi
    }


    for (( k=1; k<=3; k++ ))
    do
      myfunc
      echo hello
    done
```

Please help.

Comment: `if ABC` is not valid if `ABC` isn't a function or command, what is the real code you are executing there

Comment: edited the if condition

Comment: Please tell us: what is your current output and what did you expect?

Comment: `should not get executed and control should go to the next iteration.` - why? `echo continue` will __print__ a string `continue`, not skip the loop...

Comment: The current output is as you read it: `continue
hello 1
continue
hello 2
in the loop
hello 3 (changed to echo hello $k)
`
I really don't know what OPs question is.

Comment: I found the way...though not elegant. Based upon the if condition, I am setting a counter in the function and checking the counter value just after the function call in for loop. If it is equal to 1, I am using continue to skip echo Hello.

Comment: As per your edit - why not put `echo hello` where you have `echo continue` and don't have it after the function call at all? I suspect you're eventually trying to do an inner loop and some `break`s but this is a poor example of what your final goal is.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is all wrong and I don't know why you have an if / else if you're just interested in one output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

myfunc() {
  if [[ $k -lt 2 ]]; then
     echo "hello my value is $k"
  fi
}


for (( k=1; k<=3; k++ ))
do
  myfunc
  echo "$k just to prove it is looping" # this is always run regardless of what's in the function
done
```

output:

```
hello my value is 1
1 just to prove it is looping
2 just to prove it is looping
3 just to prove it is looping
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

    myfunc() {
      if [[ $k -gt 1 ]]; then
        echo "in the loop"
        x=1
       else
         echo Welcome
      fi
    }


    for (( k=1; k<=3; k++ ))
    do
      myfunc
        if [[ $x -eq 1 ]];then
          continue
       fi
      echo hello
    done
```

Comment: That's not a bad idea. But look up exit codes in `bash` and function return values and google, how to use exit code from function in shell conditional